# Parque si tengo una esfera en unity y colisiona con un plano que yo cree, la esfera empieza a moverse a donde ella quiera?

Tags: unity3d, unity

Tengo un plano o pista que cree en Blender y lo uso con un mesh collider y Rb, pero cuando mi esfera que se mueve toca partes del plano ejemplo alzadas donde sube la esfera y luego baja empieza a tomar la esfera movimientos que ella quiere??
Avanza hacia donde ella quiera, y me pasa siempre que colisiona si no colisiona la esfera, se mueve perfectamente, ¿Saben por qué es?

**Código para rotar sobre la esfera:**

```
public class CameraRotar : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject playerGO;
    public GameObject referencia;
    private Vector3 distancia;

    public GameObject controllerSceneGO;
    public ControllerScene controllerSceneScript;

    public ControllerPlayer scriptController;

    void InicioComponentes()
    {
        scriptController = GetComponent<ControllerPlayer>();
        playerGO = GameObject.Find("Player");
        distancia = transform.position - playerGO.transform.position;

        controllerSceneGO = GameObject.Find("ControllerScene");
        controllerSceneScript = controllerSceneGO.GetComponent<ControllerScene>();
    }

    void Start()
    {
        InicioComponentes();
    }
    void LateUpdate()
    {
        transform.position = playerGO.transform.position + distancia;
        transform.LookAt(playerGO.transform.position);

        if (controllerSceneScript.InicioJuego == true && controllerSceneScript.TerminoJuego == false)
        {
            distancia = Quaternion.AngleAxis(Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * 2, Vector3.up) * distancia;

            Vector3 copiaRotacion = new Vector3(0, transform.eulerAngles.y, 0);
            referencia.transform.eulerAngles = copiaRotacion;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Si publicas tu código seria de gran ayuda para comprender por que pasa tu problema y como solucionarlo.

Comment: transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * velocidad * Time.deltaTime);
            transform.Translate(Vector3.right * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * velocidad * Time.deltaTime);
            transform.Translate(-Vector3.back * Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * velocidad * Time.deltaTime);

Comment: transform.position = playerGO.transform.position + distancia;
        transform.LookAt(playerGO.transform.position);

        if (controllerSceneScript.InicioJuego == true && controllerSceneScript.TerminoJuego == false)
        {
            distancia = Quaternion.AngleAxis(Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * 2, Vector3.up) * distancia;
            
            Vector3 copiaRotacion = new Vector3(0, transform.eulerAngles.y, 0);
            referencia.transform.eulerAngles = copiaRotacion;
        }

Comment: Esto pegalo en tu pregunta, no en los comentarios.

Comment: Eso es lo que utilizo para mover mi player y poder rotar la camara sobre el con el mouse, pero, si no coliciona la esfera todo funciona de maravilla, pero si llega a colicionar ejemplo, con un cubo, con un rigibody, el mover el mouse sobre la esfera empieza muy loco, al moverlo avanza la esfera y hasta llega a atravesar los planos en donde y se cae al vacio

Comment: Dices que es una esfera chocando con un plano, pero pones que choca con partes alzadas? A que se refiere esto, siendo un plano no debería tener partes alzadas, si tu mesh no es totalmente plana es posible que la física de unity este calculando los movimientos de la bola al chocar con esas irregularidades.